# deformation of SVG file. Bezier Curves?

Tags: opengl, svg, 2d, bezier, elliptic-curve

I have an SVG file.This file shows the outline of cartoon character(2D character).
My question is, can I make a program that It allows the user to interact with the outline and deform it.
An example is, to pull the outline of character's arm, with the mouse,and the arm gets bigger.

I suppose that Bezier Curves and Elliptical Arcs is a solution.I also wonder if i use OPENGL, I might be more flexible to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is likely to be closed as it stands. Right now, the answer to all of those is something like "Yeah, you could do that", but at least with what you've told us, it's hard to say much more than that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your respond Jerry, I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome, for what little it was worth. What I was really getting at is whether you can rewrite it to allow more specific answers. For example, did you want to know *how* to do things like that? What have you done so far -- do you (for example) have code to render the SVG file as-is? It would probably also help to know what platform and/or libraries you're using/planning to use.

Comment: I'm working on it, and I decide to use Batik,so I can manipulate SVG documents with Java IN Eclipse.So far it is working for me.. Your advice are very helpful, again thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interaction aspect you'll need to deal with yourself. There is a recent OpenGL extension, [NV_path_rendering](http://developer.nvidia.com/nv-path-rendering) which makes accurate, hardware-accelerated rendering of SVG and other vector formats pretty simple. The SDK includes at least one example where interaction with control points is shown, which might make a good starting place for you. Obviously, this would require you/the end user to have a GPU which supports the extension. [Here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IDyZof2pRI) of the developer explaining the extension and what it can do.

Comment: Justin you just make my life easier!!Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> I also wonder if i use OPENGL, I might be more flexible to do that.

OpenGL will not make things easier in any way. OpenGL is a drawing API, not some kind of magic scene and geometry manager. All it gives you are points, lines and triangles and methods to define how those are to be drawn to a framebuffer.

Interaction with the user lies completely outside the scope of OpenGL.

Comment: I absolutly understand what you mean.My concideration is that I'm more comfortable with Java.So the only way to use OpenGL,I think is JOGL. Is JOGL as good as if I were used OpenGL with C++ ?

Answer (score 0):

[iscriptdesign](http://www.iscriptdesign.com) allows you to create interactive graphics, but you need to program/script those yourself.